# AngularJS + Elasticsearch - How to search for documents

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch

I am using AngularJS with ElasticSearch.

Until now I have been playing around with ElasticSearch using the `curl` command in my terminal.

Now, I wish to perform a search in AngularJS on my elastic search indices. How do I do it? I assume using $http.get() but I could not find an example anywhere.

Basically, how do I convert the following:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/mark/_search?pretty=true&size=100' -d '{
    "term": {
        "tag": "comedy"
    }
}'
```

to an Angular request? That is how do I achieve the above in AngularJS inside my controller?

Comment: Take a look at elastic.js. They have created an angular service to wrap calls to elastic engine (tutorial http://www.fullscale.co/blog/2013/02/28/getting_started_with_elasticsearch_and_AngularJS_searching.html )

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch has released an official JS client. You can find it on github: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-js

I found the following example https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-js/issues/19 to be helpful in setting up the client instance. Once you have the client set up, (client is 'es' and queryTerm would be mapped to a search box or similar) you can perform searches like so:

```
esApp.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope, es) {
es.cluster.health(function (err, resp) {
    if (err) {
        $scope.data = err.message;
    } else {
        $scope.data = resp;
    }
});

$scope.search = function() {
    es.search({
        index: 'your_index',
        size: 50,
        body: {
            query: {
                query_string: {
                    default_field: 'title', 
                    query: ($scope.queryTerm || '*')
                }
            }
        }
    }).then(function (resp) {
        $scope.results = resp.hits.hits;
        $scope.hitCount = resp.hits.total;
        }, function (err) {
            $scope.results(err.message);
    });
};
```